# Process builder throwing error

Tags: process-builder, flow

When I remove the Account corporate account field value (Account.parentid) in the record at the link below (in our sandbox environment at the org ID indicated), I get an error in the flow.

> An error occurred at element myRule_1_A1 (FlowRecordUpdate).  The flow
>   failed to access the value for
>   myVariable_current.Parent.Distribution_Model__c because it hasn't been
>   set or assigned.

---

This report lists the elements that the flow interview executed. The report is a beta feature. 
We welcome your feedback on IdeaExchange.

```
Flow Details 
Flow Name: Account_on_create_sync_corp_Account_info 
Type: Workflow 
Version: 12 
Status: Active 
Flow Interview Details 
Interview Label: Account_on_create_sync_corp_Account_info-12_Account 
Current User: A1
Start time: 10/13/2015 3:56 PM 
Duration: 0 seconds 
How the Interview Started 
A1 started the flow interview. 
Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started. 
myVariable_old = xuyzzdcsd
myVariable_current = sdfsdfsdgfsgdfg
ASSIGNMENT: myVariable_waitStartTimeAssignment 
{!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} Equals {!Flow.CurrentDateTime} 
Result 
{!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} = "10/13/2015 3:56 PM" 
DECISION: myDecision 
Executed this outcome: myRule_1 
Outcome conditions: and 
1. {!formula_myRule_1} (true) Equals true 
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)
```

Is the cause of error the value of `myVariable_current.Parent.Distribution_Model__c`  which in process builder set by reference  as `account.parent.distribution_model_c`?

In database it is set as false

Comment: I am getting a similar error with a Process I am currently working on debugging. Would be curious to know the answer to this as well.

Comment: In My case the error is due to the assignment ,As the value is not correctly referenced

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it's expecting a value on the Account.parentid and will present an error when you remove it. Maybe add an extra filter on the myRule_1_A1, something like isnull(parentid) = False

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding conditions like below:

```
If ( and(not( isnull( parentid)), not(isblank(parentid))),....
```